Where does DataGridView get its default DateTime format?
I am trying to determine where the DataGridView is getting its default format string to convert a DateTime to a String.

As seen in the screenshot, on my system the date format used is yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt. Seconds are not displayed. However, looking through the various CultureInfo objects, there is no single date format that matches.
For a given DateTime, a matching output string could be generated using:
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
var ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var df = ci.DateTimeFormat;
String s = d.ToString(df.ShortDatePattern) + " " + d.ToString(df.ShortTimePattern);

However, it is doubtful this is actually what is being done. It would make more sense if there was a single format being used, not two separate formats concatenated by a space. Or is that what is being done?
public static void TestDgv() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, AllowUserToAddRows = false, AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells };
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("DateTimeColumn", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { now });
    dgv.DataSource = table;

    Form f = new Form();
    f.Controls.Add(dgv); // displays format yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt
    Application.Run(f); // e.g. 2024-10-30 4:29 PM

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo c1 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo c2 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo c3 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    foreach (var ci in new [] { c1, c2, c3 }) {
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine(ci == c1 ? "CurrentCulture" : ci == c2 ? "CurrentUICulture" : "InvariantCulture");

        DateTimeFormatInfo d = ci.DateTimeFormat;
        String s1 = d.FullDateTimePattern;
        String s2 = d.LongDatePattern;
        String s3 = d.LongTimePattern;
        String s4 = d.MonthDayPattern;
        String s5 = d.ShortDatePattern;
        String s6 = d.ShortTimePattern;
        String s7 = d.SortableDateTimePattern;
        String s8 = d.UniversalSortableDateTimePattern;
        String s9 = d.YearMonthPattern;
        
        foreach (String ss in new [] { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9 }) {
            sb.AppendLine(now.ToString(ss) + "\t" + ss);
        }
    }
}

/*
CurrentCulture
Wednesday, October 30, 2024 4:29:46 PM  dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
Wednesday, October 30, 2024 dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
4:29:46 PM  h:mm:ss tt
30 October  d MMMM
2024-10-30  yyyy-MM-dd
4:29 PM h:mm tt
2024-10-30T16:29:46 yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
2024-10-30 16:29:46Z    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
October, 2024   MMMM, yyyy

CurrentUICulture
Wednesday, October 30, 2024 4:29:46 PM  dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
Wednesday, October 30, 2024 dddd, MMMM d, yyyy
4:29:46 PM  h:mm:ss tt
October 30  MMMM d
10-30-2024  M/d/yyyy
4:29 PM h:mm tt
2024-10-30T16:29:46 yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
2024-10-30 16:29:46Z    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
October 2024    MMMM yyyy

InvariantCulture
Wednesday, 30 October 2024 16:29:46 dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
Wednesday, 30 October 2024  dddd, dd MMMM yyyy
16:29:46    HH:mm:ss
October 30  MMMM dd
10-30-2024  MM/dd/yyyy
16:29   HH:mm
2024-10-30T16:29:46 yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
2024-10-30 16:29:46Z    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
2024 October    yyyy MMMM
*/


My conclusion is that concatenation of ShortDatePattern and ShortTimePattern is actually what DataGridView is using as the default format. At some point, it would be nice to confirm that in the C# source code.

That is, in the System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter class, it has the following line of code, format = formatInfo.ShortDatePattern + " " + formatInfo.ShortTimePattern; Although I haven't found the reference of DateTimeConverter in the DataGridView class.

Not sure if you have tried it, but setting CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and/or CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture has effect that you might want. See code example below:
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

    //Culture for any thread
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;

    //Culture for UI in any thread
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, AllowUserToAddRows = false, AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells };
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("DateTimeColumn", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Rows.Add(new Object[] { now });
    dgv.DataSource = table;

    Form f = new Form1();
    f.Controls.Add(dgv); 
    Application.Run(f); 
}

And the results:
With pl-PL culture

With en-US culture

